# How to eliminate Metadata from all columns in a Spark Table? (Java)

Tags: java, dataframe, apache-spark, metadata, multiple-columns

I have a dataframe `df` with four columns `id`, `ts`, `lat` and `lon`. If I run `df.schema()` in debug mode, I get

```
 0 = {StructField@13126} "StructField(id,LongType,true)"
  name = "id"
  dataType = {LongType$@12993} "LongType"
  nullable = true
  metadata = {Metadata@13065} "{"encoding":"UTF-8"}"
 1 = {StructField@13127} "StructField(ts,LongType,true)"
  name = "timestamp"
  dataType = {LongType$@12993} "LongType"
  nullable = true
  metadata = {Metadata@13069} "{"encoding":"UTF-8"}"
 2 = {StructField@13128} "StructField(lat,DoubleType,true)"
  name = "position_lat"
  dataType = {DoubleType$@13034} "DoubleType"
  nullable = true
  metadata = {Metadata@13073} "{"encoding":"UTF-8"}"
 3 = {StructField@13129} "StructField(lon,DoubleType,true)"
  name = "position_lon"
  dataType = {DoubleType$@13034} "DoubleType"
  nullable = true
  metadata = {Metadata@13076} "{"encoding":"UTF-8"}"
```

Now, I want to get rid of all metadata,, i.e. `"{"encoding":"ZSTD"}"`shouold be replaced by `""` for each column. Please note that my actual table has many columns, so the solution needs to be somewhat generic. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use encode("XX","ignore")

Example :

```
  Val df=data.map(lambda x: x.encode("ascii", "ignore").
```

Comment: Hi and thank you for your reply. I have some questions regarding this:
1) What is "data"?
2) Closing bracket missing?
3) Can you post this as Java code not Scala?